# Does dd read every possible byte from the SD card?

Tags: linux, partitioning, unix, data-recovery, sd-card

I have this damaged 16 GB MicroSD card which is hardly readable by a card reader (one of my two readers recognized it) and it shows up in the system as a drive with a single raw partition with 200-ish MB of space.

My idea was to mess with disk geometry with testdisk by increasing the number of cylinders, but everything beyond those 200 MB caused read errors.

Also, I tried to dd the desired number of bytes (16GB) from the device, but it gave me just those 200MB again.

So my question is, does the result of dd's work prove that those 200MB are all the space that survived, and there's no "software" way to make dd read more?

Comment: Have you tried `testdisk` and `ddrescue`? These are the tools most likely to be able to access inaccessible data.

Comment: `ddrescue` is a good idea but do not try to run `testdisk` on a failing device. Make a copy first. By the way, if it shows up as ~200 MB, it is likely a broken controller.

Comment: Yes, I tried testdisk. It included scan for a broken partition (regular + deep) and changing the number of cylinders (hoping that the whole 16GB would become available). None of that worked:( Regarding the controller, are there some recipes how to make it work, even for a short time? Temperature maybe?..